# how to get previous active class object

Tags: jquery, class

I have the following code

```
<ul class="color_class">
   <li><a class="" id="red">Red</a></li>
   <li><a class="" id="white">White</a></li>
   <li><a class="" id="blue">Blue</a></li>
   <li><a class="" id="green">Green</a></li>
   <li><a class="active" id="">All</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am changing color via jquery so that I want to change active class from one  to another.

I can easily add new class to new one (clicked)  but I am not able to find previous  which class was active so that I can remove it.

I can add class as

```
$('#'+color).removeClass().addClass('active'); //where color is the id name
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.color_class li a').removeClass('active');
$('#'+color).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.find`.

```
$('.color_class').find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select `.active` and removeClass()

```
 $('.color_class .active').removeClass();
```